# Reset sequence to a specific value for test purposes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to reset sequence to specific value for test purposes.
First decrement sequence with 100. After test execution I'll increment sequence with 100.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_a RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(id) FROM House.Report) - 100;
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax nead '(' -
```

Comment: `RESTART WITH <constant>`

Comment: To back up @jarlh 's statement, see the [Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM House.Report) - 100
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(200) = 'ALTER SEQUENCE seq_a RESTART WITH ' + CAST(@max AS CHAR(5))
EXEC(@stmt)
```